# Deixar parte do APP em library

Tags: android, eclipse

Tenho um APP com um pacote(Package) separado para notificação PUSH, gostaria de pegar esse pacote e transformar ele em *Library*, para que nos futuros apps somente adiciono a *Library* no meu projeto.

Como posso fazer isso?

**EDIT**

IDE: Eclipse

Comment: Android Studio, Eclipse ou outro? Tente [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/177836/edit) e detalhar melhor sua questão, para que possa obter melhores respostas.

Comment: Desculpe, estou usando Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o Eclipse é possível criar um arquivo JAR contendo as classes e as informações do projeto. Diferentemente dos arquivos `.jar`, os arquivos AAR, criados possivelmente usando Android Studio, podem conter recursos Android e um arquivo de manifesto, o que permite empacotar recursos compartilhados como *layouts* e *drawables*, além de classes e métodos Java.

Para criar uma *lib* Você vai seguir o mesmo fluxo para criar um novo projeto, porém aparecerá uma *flag* com a seguinte mensagem:

> Mark this project as a lib.

Veja na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo depois basta importar para dentro do seu projeto principal como uma *library*. Para acesso, clique o botão direito do *mouse* no projeto e vá em *proprieties > Android*. Veja na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja também como [criar uma biblioteca](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html?hl=pt-br) usando Android Studio

Comment: Perfeito! Já comecei a fazer aqui. Me tira mais uma dúvida preciso passar o valor de uma variável que está no app para minha Library. Como posso fazer isso da melhor maneira?

Comment: @William não entendi. Você quer enviar um valor para a library, para que ela te devolva alguma coisa?

Comment: @William se for isso, por exemplo você pode criar um método calculaRaio(String cicunferencia) que retorna um double. Ai você vai importar a library e chamando o método calculaRaio(circ) passando a circunferência como parâmetro. Esse é uma forma tradicional de fazer. ^^

Comment: Ok vou fazer um método, é que não sabia que dava para chamar um método do app dentro da Library. Tenho um string que no app que preciso que a library tenha acesso.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faço assim: (partindo do princípio q voce saiba usar o github

1. No android studio, vá no arquivo *build.gradle(Module: app)* e, lá em cima, mude de `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` para `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`
2. Importe o projeto no github dentro do próprio android studio. Vá em VCS>Import into version control > Share project on github (obviamente aqui voce vai ter que ter uma conta no *github* e o *github Desktop* instalado no pc)
3. Vá em https://jitpack.io/ e no campo *Git repo URL* cole o link do seu repositório que foi criado no github e depois dá um *Look up*.
4. Aí é só seguir os passos (são bem simples) nas imagens que aparecem logo abaixo no site do jitpack (que basicamente é só add a lib no seu projeto normal).
5. Pronto!!

Comment: Obrigado Mr_Anderson, saberia me dizer como faço isso usando Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

É bem tranquilo de fazer isso..

Primeiro você vai precisar abrir o `build.gradle` do módulo que você deseja que se comporte como uma biblioteca, e, em seguida, trocar `apply plugin: com.android.application` por `apply plugin: com.android.library`

Agora ele vai criar um .AAR ao invés de um .APK.

Pra adicionar uma depêndencia também é tranquilo, aconselho que você dê uma lida aqui: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html

Comment: Não sou experiente em Android ainda, então por questão de conhecimento, gostaria de saber quais as vantagens de se fazer esse procedimento?

Comment: Obrigado Max Fratane, saberia me dizer como faço isso usando Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Eu recentemente tive a mesma necessidade. Li um post do João Gabriel e resolvi meus problemas. Segue link:

[Como criar suas próprias bibliotecas](https://medium.com/@jgabrielafreitas/como-criar-suas-pr%C3%B3prias-bibliotecas-b86e4ad77b92#.4xo7b3yav)